# How do I pass the textbox text in a command as a parameter WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, command

So I have my MainWindow.xaml with a textbox on it.

```
<Window x:Class="HelloICommand.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        ...
    <Grid>
        <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="337,195,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120">
            <TextBox.InputBindings>
                <KeyBinding Command="{Binding }" Key="Enter"></KeyBinding>
            </TextBox.InputBindings>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And as you can see I want to bind my enter key to where I can click enter and it shows a messagebox with the text that is in the textbox.

In my MainWindow.cs I set the datacontext like this.

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ServerViewModel();
        }
```

And then I have the actual ServerViewModel with everything else in it
This is where I run into the issue, how do I pass the text from the TextBox to that method right there so I can see the message everytime I click enter.

```
class ServerViewModel
{
    private TextBoxCommand textCommand { get; private set; }
    public ServerViewModel()
    {
        textCommand = new TextBoxCommand(SendMessage);
    }

    //How do I pass the text from the textbox as a parameter here?
    public void SendMessage()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("");
    }
}
```

ICommand Interface

```
class TextBoxCommand : ICommand
    {
        public Action _sendMethod;

        public TextBoxCommand(Action SendMethod)
        {
            _sendMethod = SendMethod;
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {

        }

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

The view can only bind to commands if they are public properties. This means the first step is to define your command as a public (readonly) property:

```
public TextBoxCommand TextCommand { get; }
```

The [ICommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand(v=vs.110).aspx) interface allows to pass an object as a parameter to its execution function. If your implementation of a command, `TextBoxCommand` allows passing this parameter, simply add the parameter to your method, cast it as a string, and show your message:

```
private void SendMessage(object parameter)
{
    MessageBox.Show((string)parameter);
}
```

If your `TextBoxCommand` doesn't allow passing a parameter, a simple implementation like shown at [How to implement a reusable ICommand](https://wpftutorial.net/DelegateCommand.html) will do the trick. Just replace your `TextBoxCommand` with the `DelegateCommand` of the tutorial.

To execute the command correctly from your view, you now need to bind the command to the `TextCommand` property. The second step is to set the text of the text box as command parameter. With this name you are able to bind to the `Text` property and pass it as a parameter to your command. Therefore you need to name your text box. Here is the minimal example:

```
<TextBox x:Name="yourTextBox>
    <TextBox.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="Enter"
                    Command="{Binding TextCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=yourTextBox}"/>
    </TextBox.InputBindings>
</TextBox>
```

Comment: But what about my constructor, as you can see im my Example I am assigning my property a value `textCommand = new TextBoxCommand(SendMessage);` how do I pass it the proper parameter because `SendMessage()` not takes a object as a parameter so doing this  `textCommand = new TextBoxCommand(SendMessage());` would return an error because there is no parameter

Comment: Yes, this could be a problem of your `TextBoxCommand`. I will add a solution to my answer.

Comment: are you using MessageBox.Show inside the viewmodel?

Comment: Typically you would not. A possible solution would be to use an injected service like described in [MessageBox using MVVM Patterns](http://blog.brentmckendrick.com/mvvm-tips-how-to-show-a-message-box-or-dialog-in-mvvm-silverlight/). Since this was not the scope of the question I will not treat this in my answer.